# Connecting to OpenVZ Container that uses NAT

Tags: nat, openvz

lets say i do not have enough IPs to allocate to each container, how would someone connect that container if it has no public address? (using NAT for that container) the address would be private right? so how does one from an external network connect to it?

Answer (score 1):

The same way one establishes connections from outside any NAT to inside: via port forwarding.

You use iptables to forward one or more ports on the host to one or more ports on the guest. Needless to say, you will likely be able to assign each host port to a single guest port. As an example, if you have a webserver's container, you will want to forward ports 80 and 443. After doing this, no other containers will be able to use those ports.

For this reason, and if you need to provide multiple webserver containers, you may want to consider running a reverse proxy on the host or on a guest that can inspect HTTP host headers/urls and proxy connections to the appropriate location.

Answer (score 1):

My approach is the following:

- Run each container with a separate globally routable IPv6 address.
- Run a reverse proxy on a single globally routable IPv4 address. The proxy can use the `Host` header (in case of http) and SNI (in case of https) to proxy each client to the IPv6 address of the proper container.
- Additionally the gateway between containers and external network can provide Teredo and 6to4 relays for your containers, such that in case clients using one of those tunnel methods can get a reliable connection to your IPv6 adresses.

Comment: well. this is IPV4 only. Thanks for the Tip

Comment: @James Given that IPv6 is the long-term solution to your problem, now would be a good time to start doing dual-stack.

Comment: I understand but, i do not run a production server. just started this thread to clear my doubts and understanding of how am i able to connect to a NATed Container. with no Public address.

Yes IPV6 is the way to go in long term